# Get the result of query where one column is the conditional sum of a column in another table

Tags: mysql

Got two tables u and pp. Each entry in pp uses two unique identifiers user and proyect to index a third value named participation.

So If I want to get the sum of participation of all proyects for a single user (user 2 in this example) I'd do:

```
SELECT SUM(participation) AS sum FROM pp WHERE user='2'
```

This works. However what I want is the user data (name and lastname) along with the total participation which is in table U and each user has a unique identifier named keyid, which correspond to the user value of table pp. I would like, if possible, to get all my data in only 1 query. So this is what I've tried:

```
SELECT u.name, u.lastname , u.username, u.keyid, SUM(pp.participation) FROM u, pp WHERE pp.user=u.keyid;
```

To provide an example as suggested.

Table pp contains

```
user proyect participation
1    1       25   
1    2       36
2    1       51   
2    2       6

Table u
name  lastname  username keyid
John  Doe       jdoe     1  
Jane  Doef      janed    2
```

The result I spect is

```
name  lastname  username sum
John  Doe       jdoe     61  
Jane  Doef      janed    57
```

However this got me a single result where the sum column was the SUM of the entire participation column.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider providing some sample data and expected output.

Comment: You already have an answer for this check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e18bb/1)

Use `join` and `group by`

```
SELECT 
  u.name, 
  u.lastname , 
  u.username, 
  u.keyid, 
  SUM(pp.participation) 
FROM u
join pp
WHERE pp.user=u.keyid
group by u.keyid
```

Comment: This got me exactly what I wanted!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok . I write a fiddle for you . Please see this

Answer (score 0):

Try with LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY statements. LEFT JOIN helps you relate one table with another given a column. GROUP BY will group rows and apply SUM on each group

```
SELECT u.name, u.lastname , u.username, u.keyid, SUM(pp.participation) FROM pp LEFT JOIN u ON pp.user = u.keyid GROUP BY pp.user
```

EDIT: sorry, imran answered while I was writing

EDIT 2: If you want all that data but for an specific user you can still use the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT u.name, u.lastname , u.username, u.keyid, SUM(pp.participation) FROM pp LEFT JOIN u ON pp.user = u.keyid WHERE pp.user = '2'
```